# Referencing a Laravel model by qualified name vs ::class

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I've seen various Laravel tutorials reference a related model in two different ways:

`return $this->belongsTo('App\User');`

`return $this->belongsTo(User::class');`

Most of the tutorials I've seen use the second method, but the first seems like it would be easier to resolve given that the namespace is present.  What is the difference?

Comment: The second way is more IDE friendly as it can be easily detected and refactored. for example, you can search for class usage across the project with it, which is very hard using the first way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these options will work exactly the same since `User::class` returns `'App\User'`. Laravel has a mix of both in its documentation.

The advantage of the second option is that IDEs can interpret it which allows for things like automatic renaming the name or namespace across all files and clicking through to the actual class.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO I would go with

```php
return $this->belongsTo(User::class);`
```

If you have to refractor your app and you change your Models namespace, for example you want to move them under `App\Models\`, you only have to change the `use` clause from:

```php
use App\User;
```

To:

```
use App\Models\User;
```

And that is only **one** replace for each class that use the `User` model (at the start of the file).

On the contrary if you use `return $this->belongsTo('App\User');` you have to search/replace in maybe different parts of your class files. And if you have lot of *Models/Controllers* can be timesaving and less error prone.